# Spin wheel result to be already controlled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random, probability

I'm using this code to create a spinning wheel. But I want to control the result. For example the prize $10000 I want it with less percentage. So, not anyone can get maybe 1 in 500 people. I didn't know how to set percentage for them. if anyone can help I'll appreciate it. Thank you in advance.
If you can give me any hint to help me continue and know what to do next.

this is the code that I have used

**I UPDATED THE WHOLE CODE TO ADD PROBABILITY FOR THE RANDOM. ALSO, I ADDED MORE PRIZES. NOW I HAVE A PROBLEM WITH THE DESIGN AND THE PROBABILITY ITSELFT. ALSO, THE CODE IS VERY LONG.
I HOPE YOU CAN HELP ME WITH THE PROABILITY AND DESIGN ISSUE**

```js
    //set default degree (360*5)
  // I TRIED FOR 12 PRIZES TO MULTIPLY 360*11 BUT NOTHING CHANGES
var degree = 1800;
//number of clicks = 0
var clicks = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    /*WHEEL SPIN FUNCTION*/
    $('#spin').click(function(){
        
        //add 1 every click
        clicks ++;
        
        /*multiply the degree by number of clicks
      generate random number between 1 - 360, 
    then add to the new degree*/
        var newDegree = degree*clicks;
        var extraDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 -1+1 )+1);
        
        if(extraDegree =0.05)
        {
            
            var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 -1+1 )+1);
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
            
                $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
        }
        else if(extraDegree =0.05)
        {
            var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (60 -30+1 )+30);
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
            
                $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
        }
        else if (extraDegree =0.10)
            {
                var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 -60+1 )+60);
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
                
                    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
            }
        else if (extraDegree =5)
            {
                var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (120 -90+1 )+90)
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
                
                    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
            }
        else if (extraDegree =5)
            {
                var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (150 -120+1 )+120);
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
                
                    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
            }
        else if (extraDegree =5)
            {
                var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (180 -150+1 )+150)
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
                
                    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
            }
        else if (extraDegree =5)
            {
                var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (210 -180+1 )+180)
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
                
                    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
            }
        else if (extraDegree =13)
            {
                var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (240 -210+1 )+210)
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
                
                    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
            }
        else if (extraDegree =16)
            {
                var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (270 -240+1 )+240)
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
                
                    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
            }
        else if (extraDegree =16)
            {
                var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 -270+1 )+270);
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
                
                    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
            }
        else if (extraDegree =16.8)
            {
                var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (330 -300+1 )+300)
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
                
                    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
            }
        else if (extraDegree =18)
            {
                var newextraDegree=Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 -330+1 )+330)
            totalDegree = newDegree+newextraDegree;
                
                    $('#wheel .sec').each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var noY = 0;
            
            var c = 0;
            var n = 700;    
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                c++;                
                if (c === n) { 
                    clearInterval(interval);                
                }   
                    
                var aoY = t.offset().top;
                $("#txt").html(aoY);
                console.log(aoY);
                
                /*23.7 is the minumum offset number that 
                each section can get, in a 30 angle degree.
                So, if the offset reaches 23.7, then we know
                that it has a 30 degree angle and therefore, 
                exactly aligned with the spin btn*/
                if(aoY < 11.94){
                    console.log('<<<<<<<<');
                    $('#spin').addClass('spin');
                    setTimeout(function () { 
                        $('#spin').removeClass('spin');
                    }, 100);    
                }
            }, 10);
            
            $('#inner-wheel').css({
                'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'          
            });
         
            noY = t.offset().top;
            
        });
            }
        
        
        
        
        
        /*let's make the spin btn to tilt every
        time the edge of the section hits 
        the indicator*/
    
    });
    
    
    
});//DOCUMENT READY
```

```css
    #awardPanel {
padding:10px;
color:green;
text-align:center;
}

    *{  margin:0;   padding:0; }

body{
    background:#eaeaea;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

a{
    color:#34495e;  
}




/*WRAPPER*/
#wrapper{ 
    margin: 40px auto 0;    
    width:266px; 
    position:relative;
}

#txt{
    color:#eaeaea;  
}


/*WHEEL*/
#wheel{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border-radius:50%;  
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:8px solid #fff;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 0px 10px, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0px 3px 0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#wheel:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    border:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width:242px;
    height:242px;
    border-radius:50%;
    z-index:1000;   
}

#inner-wheel{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    
    -webkit-transition: all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    -moz-transition:    all 6 cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    -o-transition:      all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    -ms-transition:     all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
    transition:         all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99); 
}

#wheel div.sec{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 130px 75px 0;
    border-color: #19c transparent;
    transform-origin: 75px 129px;
    left:50px;
    top:-4px;   
    opacity:1;
}

#wheel div.sec:nth-child(1){
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  border-color: blue transparent;  
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(2){
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  border-color: white transparent;  
}
        
        
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(3){
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  border-color: blue transparent;  
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(4){
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
  border-color: white transparent;  
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(5){
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
  border-color: blue transparent;  
}
#wheel div.sec:nth-child(6){
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  border-color: white transparent;  
}
        #wheel div.sec:nth-child(7){
  transform: rotate(210deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(210deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(210deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(210deg);
  border-color: blue transparent;  
}
        #wheel div.sec:nth-child(8){
  transform: rotate(240deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(240deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(240deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
  border-color: white transparent;  
}
        #wheel div.sec:nth-child(9){
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  border-color: blue transparent;  
}
        #wheel div.sec:nth-child(10){
  transform: rotate(300deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(300deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
  border-color: white transparent;  
}
        #wheel div.sec:nth-child(11){
  transform: rotate(330deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(330deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(330deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(330deg);
  border-color: blue transparent;  
}
        #wheel div.sec:nth-child(12){
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  border-color: white transparent;  
}

        

#wheel div.sec .fa{
    margin-top: -100px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000000;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-left:-15px;
    
    text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px -1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 0px;
}




#spin{
    width:68px;
    height:68px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-34px 0 0 -34px;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0px 3px 0px;
    z-index:1000;
    background:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;    
  -ms-user-select: none;     
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;   
}


#spin:after{
    content:"SPIN"; 
    text-align:center;
    line-height:68px;
    color:#CCC;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100000;
    width:68px;
    height:68px;
    display:block;
}

#spin:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 20px 28px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
    top:-12px;
    left:14px;
}

#inner-spin{
    width:54px;
    height:54px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-27px 0 0 -27px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:red;
    z-index:999;
    box-shadow:rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px -2px 0px inset, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 2px 0px inset,  rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0px 0px 5px ;
    
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(234,234,234,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */    
}

#spin:active #inner-spin{
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0px 0px 5px inset;
}

#spin:active:after{
    font-size:15px; 
}



#shine{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99)), color-stop(9%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.99) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.91) 9%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */


opacity:0.1;
    
}



/*ANIMATION*/
@-webkit-keyframes hh {
  0%, 100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  50%{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hh {
   0%, 100%{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  50%{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

.spin {
  -webkit-animation: hh 0.1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: hh 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="wheel">
                <div id="inner-wheel">
                    <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;">$10000</span></div>
                        <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;">$8000</span></div>
                        <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;" >$6000</span></div>
                        <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;" >$4000</span></div>
                    <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;">$2000</span></div>
                    <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;">$1000</span></div>
                    <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;">$500</span></div>
                        <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;">$300</span></div>
                        <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;" >$100</span></div>
                        <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;" >$50</span></div>
                    <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;">10% off</span></div>
                    <div class="sec"><span class="fa" style="font-size: 16px;">free spin</span></div>
                
                </div>
                            <div id="spin">
                                <div id="inner-spin"></div>
                            
                        
                    <div id="shine"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="txt"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

****Now let's say for example I want to get a random number between 1 and 360 and `Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 -1+1 )+1)`
Now I want to create a probability out of 100
if the number was between 1 and 30 the probability will be 0.05,
if the number was between 30 and 60 the probability will be 0.05,
if the number was between 60 and 90 the probability will be 0.10,
if the number was between 90 and 120 the probability will be 5,
if the number was between 120 and 150 the probability will be 5,
if the number was between 150 and 180 the probability will be 5,
if the number was between 180 and 210 the probability will be 5,
if the number was between 210 and 240 the probability will be 13,
if the number was between 240 and 270 the probability will be 16,
if the number was between 270 and 300 the probability will be 16,
if the number was between 300 and 330 the probability will be 16.8,
if the number was between 330 and 360 the probability will be 18,
(0.05+0.05+0.10+5+5+5+5+13+16+16+16.8+18=100)
How can I achieve this****

Comment: You are now using the RNG to determine the new angle and get the price from it right? Have you tried it the other way round? Use the RNG to get the new target and then calculate a random amount of turns and offset from the start of the target price. Then you can assign a probability to each price.

Comment: @SHell could you guide me through it

Answer (score 0):

Since your second version of the code is way to long to edit in the time I can offer I wrote a short example on how to define your price list and select a winning price.

This example uses a list of possible prices with probabilities and creates a weighted list of them. From this list a random item is chosen which identifies the winning price.

After that the angle to turn the wheel is calculated to reach a random place in the selected price (starting from 0°)

```
// Define the prices and probabilities
const prices = [
    {value: "Nothing", probability: 0.5},
    {value: "Free Spin", probability: 0.2},
    {value: "10$", probability: 0.15},
    {value: "50$", probability: 0.1},
    {value: "100$", probability: 0.04},
    {value: "1000$", probability: 0.01},
];

// The angle one the wheel one area uses (uniform sizes)
var priceAngle = 360 / prices.length;

var result = prices[0];

// Generate a list of the indices based on the probabilities
var weightedList = [];
for (let i=0; i < prices.length; i++)
{
    for (let j=0; j < prices[i].probability*100; j++)
    {
        weightedList.push(i);
    }
}

// Get a random index from the weightedList and use it to get the price
var winningPriceIndex = weightedList[Math.floor(Math.random() * weightedList.length)];
result = prices[winningPriceIndex];

// Full spins the wheel shoud turn (min. 1, max. 5)
var fullSpins = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)+1;
// Offset from 0° to the start of the price
var offsetToPrice = winningPriceIndex * priceAngle;
// Random offset from the start of the price
var additionalOffset = Math.floor(Math.random() * priceAngle);

console.log("The wheel turns " + (fullSpins * 360 + offsetToPrice + additionalOffset) 
    + "° (" + fullSpins + " full spin + " + offsetToPrice + "° + " + additionalOffset + "°)");
console.log('You won: ' + result.value);
```

This might not be the best performing solution but it should give you an idea on how to solve your problem.